# On Shabbos, if someone asks you who you are going to vote for for President, are you allowed to say?

Tags: shabbat

On Shabbos, if someone asks you who you are going to vote for for President, are you allowed to say?  Or would this be forbidden because it is talking about doing something after Shabbos which you are not allowed to do on Shabbos.

Comment: Definitely permissible. Depending on who's the incumbent and who's the challenger, and depending which one you support, it's either removing a גרף של רעי or preventing עושין גרף של רעי לכתחלה, both of which are allowed on Shabbos.

Answer (score 2):

שולחן ערוך  אורח חיים שז א

> ...שלא יהא דבורך של שבת כדבורך של חול הלכך **אסור לומר דבר פלוני** אעשה
>   למחר או סחורה פלונית אקנה למחר ו**אפילו בשיחת דברים בטלים אסור להרבות**:
>
> הגה: ובני אדם שסיפור שמועות ודברי חידושים הוא עונג להם מותר לספרם בשבת
>   כמו בחול אבל מי שאינו מתענג אסור לאמרם כדי שיתענג בהם חבירו...

Shu"A O"H 307:a

Your conversation on Shabbat should not be like your conversation on weekdays. So it's forbidden to say **I will do a certain action tomorrow** or I will buy certain goods, and even **idle matters is not to be extended**.

Rama: people who enjoy talking about news, may talk about it on Shabbat like on other days, but if one does not enjoy he may not do so for the pleasure of his friend...

I would dare to say, that since the conversation is not about the action (going to vote), but it's actually about politics, you are OK with the first part of the rule.

(You can be a big Tazdik and instead of saying "I will go to vote for X", say "I would like that X will be the president").

From the second part, it seems that you may not talk about it, at least not lengthily, unless you enjoy talk politics.

Comment: I had trouble translating "דברים בטלים", maybe it should be translated otherwise.

Comment: I’d say idle words

Comment: @AlaychemRememberMonica For what it's worth, Eliyahu Touger translates _Mishneh Torah_'s equivalent (in [Hilkhot Sabbat 24:4](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/935245/jewish/Shabbat-Chapter-Twenty-Four.htm#v4)) "ואסור להרבות בשיחה בטלה" as "_[i]t is forbidden to speak extensively about idle matters_".

Comment: @Tamir accepted